# VBA IE Automation

Tags: vba

I am trying to automate a process where I must query a website: http://rgl.faa.gov/Regulatory_and_Guidance_Library/rgAD.nsf/MainFrame?OpenFrameset

There is a input text field `<input name="query size="20"/>"` that I want to populate but I am struggling to do so. Currently I am testing my code to see if I can even reference the tag.

```
Sub fill()
Dim IE As Object
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

IE.navigate "http://rgl.faa.gov/Regulatory_and_Guidance_Library/rgAD.nsf/MainFrame?OpenFrameset"
IE.Visible = True
While IE.busy
DoEvents
Wend

For Each it In IE.Document.getElementsByTagName("input")
            If it.Name = "newquery" Then
                MsgBox ("yup")
            End If
        Next
End Sub
```

I think my issue is that the input field is in 2 framesets and a frame...

Any ideas if this is even possible to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless you know exactly which frame the input is in, this is a classical situation for a recursive search:

```
Sub fill()
  Dim IE As Object, elem As Object
  Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

  IE.navigate "http://rgl.faa.gov/Regulatory_and_Guidance_Library/rgAD.nsf/MainFrame?OpenFrameset"
  IE.Visible = True

  While IE.Busy: DoEvents: Wend
  While IE.document.readyState <> "complete": DoEvents: Wend

  Set elem = FindInputByName(IE.document, "newquery")
  If Not elem Is Nothing Then
    elem.Value = "It works!"
  End If
End Sub

Function FindInputByName(document As Object, name As String) As Object
  Dim i As Integer, subdocument As Object, elem As Variant
  Set FindInputByName = Nothing

  For i = 0 To document.frames.Length - 1
    Set subdocument = document.frames.Item(i).document
    Set FindInputByName = FindInputByName(subdocument, name)
    If Not FindInputByName Is Nothing Then Exit Function
  Next i

  For Each elem In document.getElementsByTagName("INPUT")
    If elem.name = name Then
      Set FindInputByName = elem
      Exit Function
    End If
  Next elem
End Function
```

Comment: I tried to run the code, but I ran into some errors it saids that "Object doesn't support this property or method." When debugging it highlights the area in the function For Each frame In document.frames..

Comment: Apparently the `frames` collection does not allow `For Each`. I've substituted with a regular counted `For` loop, now it seems to work. Also note that I've changed to `While IE.document.readyState <> "complete"` - I *think* that's better than polling `IE.Busy`, but I'm not entirely sure. YMMV.

Comment: I am not sure what I am doing wrong but I copy and pasted your code and receivied a new error "ByRef argument type mismatch". I tried changing it ByVal, still doesnt work as expected.

Comment: I did not have any MS Office application to test this with yesterday. Now I have, so see latest correction.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to install and use opentwebst Library : http://codecentrix.com/download.html

Don't forget to add opentwebst in project references.

It took me less time to generate the code below then writing this post :

```
Sub OpenTwebstMacro
    Dim core As ICore
    Set core = New OpenTwebstLib.core

    Dim browser As IBrowser
    Set browser = core.StartBrowser("http://rgl.faa.gov/Regulatory_and_Guidance_Library/rgAD.nsf/MainFrame?OpenFrameset")

    Call browser.FindElement("input text", "name=newquery").InputText("YOUR QUERY")
    Call browser.FindElement("input button", "uiname=Go").Click
End Sub
```